# How to enable npapi in chrome without permission to change config

Tags: google-chrome, silverlight, npapi

Is there a way to change enable npapi, that i need for silverlight in chrome without admin rights(Webpage Blocked ERR_BLOCKED_BY_ADMINISTRATOR) this chrome://flags/#enable-npapi doesn't work.

Comment: If you have the most current version of Chrome released after Sept 2015 you can't.

Answer (score 1):

Chrome has disabled npapi as of September 2015.

[The Final Countdown for NPAPI](http://blog.chromium.org/2014/11/the-final-countdown-for-npapi.html)

> In September 2015 we will remove the override and NPAPI support will be permanently removed from Chrome. Installed extensions that require NPAPI plugins will no longer be able to load those plugins.